# Please explain why "would" is used in the following sentences?

Tags: meaning-in-context, conversation, will-would

Please explain why "would" is used in the following sentences (it's shown in its contracted form).

Situation 1.

> A: We have a special course that focuses on healthy food.
>
> B: I don't think **I'd** be interested in that.

Situation 2.

> A. What about the course specialising in vegetarian dishes?
>
> B: Oh. that sounds interesting.
>
> A: it gets booked up very quickly so **you'd** need to check if it was
>   available.

Situation 3.

> A: This experiment takes very little time.
>
> B: So, **that'd** make it a good one to choose. And I don't suppose **it'd**
>   need much equipment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Situation #1 is an example of [***hedging***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hedge_(linguistics)) (using mitigating words and constructions to lessen the negative impact of an utterance). What B *actually* means is ***I am not interested in that***. But first he "tones down" his assertion by starting with ***I think*** (giving the impression that he might be wrong, and/or might change his mind), and then he continues with the modal ***would*** (***I'd be*** interested = **I would be** interested, which is further removed from "current reality" than ***I am*** interested).

Arguably, the modal ***would*** above is "justified" by the fact that A *hasn't* explicitly asked whether B is interested - so you could say what B means is ***If you were to ask me directly***, I would decide / admit that I wasn't interested (but you haven't, so it's a "hypothetical scenario" at the moment).

Situation #2 is a more straightforward hypothetical scenario - ***if*** you were to progress from "being interested" to *actually signing up*, it would be necessary to check course availability (but you wouldn't have to if you weren't interested).

Situation #3 is effectively the same as #2 - a hypothetical scenario, which ***would*** arise *if you were to choose that particular experiment.*